# I need to create a notification service but can't decide the architecture

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, architecture

I am creating a service in which i am asking user about a particular time of the day for example a user selects 7:15 PM , then user will be notified at this particular time everyday. Each user can select any time of the day and the time is stored in a NoSQL DB along with other user details, Now the problem is i need to scan database each minute to find out every user's specified time which is not ideal and very expensive. I cannot think of any other architecture,i cannot use local notifications of the phones, notifications has to be remote i.e. sent from a backend server.

Thanks for any help you could offer.

Comment: Are you sure you're not prematurely optimizing this? How long does the query take currently? I would guess it's less than 5 seconds if you have the right indexes and don't have millions of users. Running it once a minute may not be so bad.

Comment: The thing is we dont need to have millions of users , beacuse each user can have multiple data objects with their own specific time just like mutliple alarms in a single phone for which the user needs to be notified. Also i am not doing this for my personal project but for a rather big company so we do have a large user base and also this needs to be scalable to adjust to any future requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a system where you can keep data in memory, you can implement a priority queue quite cheaply - such as what I've shown for Firebase Realtime Database in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ttl

The key points for such a structure are:

- You keep all tasks in an ordered list, and then set a timer only for the first task in the list.
- If the timer expires, you execute the task and delete it.
- If an item comes in your add it in the right spot in the list.
- Either of the last two points can/will lead to a new first item in the list, so you set the timer for this new first item.

The main code is:

```
function checkFirstAndTrigger() {
  clearTimeout(timer); // clear any potentially pending timer, since we may have been interrupted
  if (first && first.exists()) {
    const deltaMs = first.child(ttlProp).val() - Date.now();
    // if the item has to be triggered now (or before now), do so
    if (deltaMs <= 0) {
      first.ref.remove(); // this will retrigger the child_added listener below
    }
    else {
      console.log(`Waiting for ${deltaMs}ms`)
      // we were triggered prematurely, wait until it's our time (or until we're interrupted)
      timer = setTimeout(checkFirstAndTrigger, deltaMs);
    }
  }
}

// Set a trigger for the first item/task in the list. This gets triggered 
// when a new first item is added, or when the current first item gets deleted.
queue.orderByChild(ttlProp).limitToFirst(1).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  // a new item became the first in the queue, either because a new one was added or because the previous first got deleted
  first = snapshot;
  checkFirstAndTrigger();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea.  You can keep a sorted list of all upcoming notifications for all users (perhaps those to fire in the next hour).  Depending on the scale of your system, you may be able to keep this sorted list of the next hour's notifications in memory.

Then, once a minute, you just look at the start of the list to see which notifications are ready to fire.  You only have to search the sorted list until you find the first notification that is not ready.

Then, depending upon how much time your sorted list in memory covers, you update the sorted list from the database to pull in new upcoming events.  If your list contains the next hour's worth of events, then you only need to update the list once an hour to get the next hour's worth of events.  In this way, you don't have to be querying the database very often.

Then, you need to also create some utility functions that capture every place you might add, remove or modify a future event so you can check if that event needs to be added or removed from the next hour's in-memory list.  So, instead of directly modifying the database, you always go through these utility functions so you can separately maintain your sorted next hour list anytime the database is updated.  Of course, the check on a database mod will have nothing extra to do if the event it is modifying is further away from now than the next hour.

Comment: But what if we have a sorted list for the next hour and a new user comes and sets up his time in this hour so he cannot be notified at that time. 

One approach i am thinking is to maintain a priority queue and whenever user sets their time enter the time in the queue and each minute a workers picks up a message and sends the notificaition to the user and again publish the message to the queue by adding 24 hour , so that the notification can be sent the next day as well.

Comment: @Shreyash - You missed the part of my answer where I explained that all mods to events in the database (including new users) have to go through a few key functions where you can keep the in-memory sorted list up to date in parallel.  Unless your database will provide a dynamic and efficient sort for you of all events, you will have to do some dual maintenance like this.  Or you could trigger a notification that a new user was added and then query that specific new user to update the in-memory sorted list if required for any events from that user.

Comment: @Shreyash - The general idea is that to do this efficiently you either have to use a native feature in your database for sorting all events (some sort of sorted index that is fast and efficient to query) or you have to dual maintain the next hour's worth of events and only go back to the database once an hour to get another hour's worth.

Comment: yes got that now. Thanks.